# How to enter HTML input in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am creating a form in html and I want to add form values in javascript array. How I can do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="array.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Input Array</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="first"/>
            <input type="text" id="second"/>
            <input type="text" id="third"/>
            <input type="text" id="fourth" />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" OnClick="array();"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

these four values in javascript array and print them on same page.

Comment: what's the purpose? why not just use serialize() ?

Comment: I am new to javascript define please.

Comment: why do you want array?

Comment: I just want to get all in javascript array and then show on the html page. After that I will use these array in my google map api for plotting marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

For eg:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This would produce the result something like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "d",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    value: "5"
  }
]
```

Note:

Do not forget to pass name in your input elements. For eg: `<input type="text" id="first" name="a" />`

Comment: Thanks buddy for this method..
Butt will you tell me that is it possible to add "saab","volvo" values through HTML input
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

Comment: sorry, couldn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>     function abc()
>     {
>         formdata= $("#form").serialize();
>         alert(formdata);
>     }
>
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <h2>Input Array</h2>
>     <form method="post" id="form">
>         <input type="text" id="first" name="a" />
>         <input type="text" id="second" name="b"/>
>         <input type="text" id="third" name="c"/>
>         <input type="text" id="fourth" name="d" />
>         <input type="button" value="Submit" OnClick="return abc();"/>
>     </form>
> </body> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is some modification to your html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="array.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Input Array</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="first" class="vals"/>
            <input type="text" id="second" class="vals"/>
            <input type="text" id="third" class="vals"/>
            <input type="text" id="fourth" class="vals"/>
            <input type="text" id="fifth" class="vals"/>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" OnClick="array();"/>
        </form>
        <p id="temp"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and your javascript function would be this

```
function array(){
    var arr = [];
    var valElements = document.getElementsByClassName("vals");
    var tempstr = "";
    /* retrieve the input from textbox
       and store in an array
    */
    for(i=0; i<valElements.length; i++){
        arr[i] = valElements[i].value;
        tempstr = tempstr+arr[i];
    }

    /* use the input on your page */
    var a = document.getElementById("temp");
    a.innerHTML = tempstr;
}
```

Comment: but when I dont know the number of values ?

Comment: so why have to given id's to the textboxes? instead you can class them together and then loop through.